# Как лучше убрать лишние нули после запятой в Decimal

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

С огромным удивлением обнаружил, что в результате вычислений в Decimal-переменной могут образоваться ненужные нули после запятой, например:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> t = Decimal('0.001')
>>> t
Decimal('0.001')
>>> t*100
Decimal('0.100')
```

Эти нули потом будут на принте, в файле или в отправляемых данных на сервер, что ему может не понравиться.
Зачем эти нули остаются? Смысла в них никакого, и вряд ли они кому-то когда-то будут нужны.
Как их лучше убрать? Навскидку приходит в голову:

```
from decimal import Decimal
t1 = Decimal('0.1000')
t2 = Decimal('1.000')
print(t1, t2)

def func(x):
    x = str(x)
    while x[-1] == '0':
        x = x[:-1]
    return Decimal(x)


print(func(t1), func(t2))
```

Но это, возможно, не самый оптимальный вариант, а возможно существует уже встроенное решение этой проблемы, о котором я не в курсе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> t
Decimal('0.100')
>>> t.normalize()
Decimal('0.1')
```

Может быть несколько причин сохранять эти нули, например, вы работаете с валютой или в другой области где нужно скрупулезно указывать точность измерений. Вот хороший обзор причин (eng): http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decifaq1.html#tzeros